# Examples of non-Riemann integrable functions that appear "in nature"?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, examples-counterexamples

I am teaching an honours calculus class, and am looking for examples on non-integrable functions that occur somewhere real in mathematics. (The standard example of 1 on $\mathbb{Q}$ and 0 elsewhere always felt slightly manufactured to me. If you can give a context for it, I would be happy about that, too).

Comment: I, too, would love to see an example. I'm guessing there's a physics application for using Lebesgue theory to handle such functions. One might first jump to quantum (since a lot of weird things happen here) but quantum wavefunctions are always assumed to be twice continuously differentiable (so they satisfy Schrodinger's equation). I think the next logical branch of physics for such things would be statistical mechanics. Maybe someone that knows enough advanced stat mech can chime in.

Comment: I also would like to know of some example of this. They're neat and math-y, but it'd be great to see where they exist "in nature".

Comment: Your question appears to ask about "non-manufactured" appearances in mathematics, but most of the comments and answers seem to be considering a more difficult question, namely "non-manufactured" appearances in physics and engineering. Nonetheless, the more difficult question is discussed in this mathoverflow question: [Is Riemannian integration sufficient in physics?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133049/is-riemannian-integration-sufficient-in-physics)

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for a function with just 1 singularity to be non-integrable: think, for example, of $\int _{-1} ^1 x^{-2}dx$. Singularities such as that do appear often enough.

It's more difficult to come up with a function that would be nowhere integrable. The reason non-Riemann integrable functions seem rare is because most functions in physics are piecewise continuous, with only isolated discontinuities.

For physical functions with more than a few isolated singularities I would suggest looking at some spectra and then write down a response function of a suitable parameter.

For example, take the resonance frequencies of an ordinary string, compute the resonance function, and write it as a function of the wavelength rather then frequency. This function is going to have infinitely many poles clustering near 0, making it non-Riemann integrable there.

A more natural and well-studied physical model that behaves very badly locally: Navier-Stokes equations. Turbulent flows behave much worse on the small scale than on the large scale; a function that maps the location of the flow to the **direction** of the flow at that point is very unlikely to be Riemann-integrable.

Comment: Should that have been $x^{-2} $?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: yes, of course, correcting.

Answer (score 2):

1. Brownian motion and other stochastic processes, and the way their integrals are related to physical concepts as well as other application areas like time-series forecasting.
2. Signal processing; particularly image and audio processing. Natural image signals have badly behaved cusps, corners, and other kinds of discontinuities that create problems if trying to reconstruct them via an algorithm that may only utilize Riemann-integrable functions. Similarly for natural audio signals. Some classes of functions that may provide for useful illustrative examples are Sobolev spaces and Bounded Variation functions. You may find good visuals by looking for examples of Total Variation inpainting.

Comment: are you sure about Brownian motion not being <em>integrable</em>?

Comment: Which type of integrability are you talking about? Riemann? Lebesgue? Lebesgue-Stieltjes? Ito? Stratanovich? Henstock-Kurzweil? ... be specific.

Comment: even Riemann, I would say..

Comment: Well then it depends on what you mean. If you mean that because Brownian motion is continuous w.p. 1, and can derive a technical definition of the random-variable-valued "thing" that "is equal" to its "integral" ... then sure, that pedantic definition satisfies. That's clearly a very different thing than what the question is asking about, which is for examples where an attempt to do a naive Riemann integration leads to an unusual outcome that doesn't have the same properties of a conventional integral. Brownian motion certainly counts for that: what's the derivative of the integral of `B_t`?

Comment: "That's clearly a very different thing..": no it is not. But even with your liberal interpretation of the question, the claim you make is incorrect as well: the derivative of the integral of a function which is continuous on an interval is equal to the function itself (essentially Royden, Real Aanalysis 3rd ed. Chap.5 Lemma 9)  and almost every sample path of Brownian motion is continuous. Now it is true that almost every sample path of Brownian motion is continuous and nowhere differentiable, but the question was not about that.Unfortunately I don't have enough points to downvote your answer.

Comment: "Once you do have enough points you should click on my user name to see other questions that I have answered and down vote those too": I don't have and didn't have any intention to do that. I just looked out of curiousity on some of your answers (some of which were interesting to me) and then stumbled upon this one. More to the point, I don't like presumptuousness (perhaps because I am guilty of it as well).

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{\cos\frac{1}{x^2}}{x}$$ is more natural, although I don't know previsely in what context it arises (likewise, I believe all functions such that as $x\rightarrow 0$ $f(x)$ oscillates infinitely often and $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$ are not Riemann integrable but more natural).